# Angular 2 Observable with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and async pipe are not working

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-template, angular2-services, ngrx

I am using an observable to return a list from service to my component and in my component I am using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and in template I am using async pipe, hoping this would give some performance benefit since Change Detection isn't performed all the time but only when new contents are available.

Below is my service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {

    public _list$: Subject<any[]>;

    private list: any[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this._list$ = <Subject<any>>new Subject();
    }

    get list$() {
        return this._list$.asObservable();
    }

    loadList() {
        //if this.list is populated through an http call the view is updated, 
        //if its a static list like below, it doesn't trigger view update.
        //this.list = ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Blue'];
        this._list$.next(this.list);
    }
}
```

In my component I have:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    templateUrl: `
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of (list$ | async);">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ListComponent {

    public list$: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(
        private _ls: ListService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.list$ = this._ls.list$;
        this._ls.loadList();
    }
}
```

The issue if the loadList contents fetch list contents through an http call, the view is updated, if the list content are static, the view isn't updated.

If I wrap list update inside setTimeout, it does trigger view update

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this._list$.next(this.list);
}, 1);
```

I just started exploring Observables, can anyone please guide whats wrong with above code?

Answer (score 4):

Just move the code fron `ngOnInit()` to the constructor. Angular tries to resolve the binding (subscribe to the observable) before `ngOnInit()` is called and fails because `thod._list$` is `null` and doesn't try later because it doesn't recognise the change.

Comment: Thank you so much Günter for your reply. But this doesnt seem to solve the issue. If loadList method in service makes an http call or if wrap it under setTimeout(() => {
    this._list$.next(this.list);
}, 1); it works otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: `setTimeout()` causes change detection to run. Did you actually try moving the code to the constructor? You could try to just move the first line to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I moved the line this.list$ = this._ls.list$;  to the constructor.

Comment: I also tried adding this.list$.subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); to the ngOnInit() to confirm if the data is actually being sent from the service or not, and the log shows the that data is actually being retrieved but the view isn't updated.

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: latest version RC 3

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. You can try RC.4 but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: One more thing I would like to add. In my actual component, this list component displays list of the selected type. And for the first time its fetched from server and added to cache (a local array of objects in service). next time when user requests same type of list, its first checked in cache if exists then its returned from cache otherwise its fetched through http. If user stays on the same component and switch between different types of lists, it works.

Comment: When user clicks a list item he is taken to a child component mapped to a route but shares same service instance so that when user goes back to the same list type, its could be served through cache. But when user goes back from item details to list, and that list of that type is to be served form cache it doesnt work.

Comment: I guess that would need a Plunker to reproduce and investigate.

Comment: I do not have a live service for that, so it would be difficult :(

Comment: You could use a mock Http service

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If not, I guess it might be related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10816